# How to create LVG (Volume Group)

Tags: linux

```
mount
```

output:

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

For fdisk -l command:

```
fdisk -l
```

here is output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1499.7 GB, 1499748892672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182334 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008c375

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          14      103424   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              14         536     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3             536      182335  1460299776   83  Linux
```

here is the command i try to run:

```
vgcreate vg_dlp /dev/sda3
```

the output i get:

```
  No physical volume label read from /dev/sda3
  Can't open /dev/sda3 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
  Unable to add physical volume '/dev/sda3' to volume group 'vg_dlp'.
```

im trying to create the volume group for /dev/sda3, but i get error. is it possible for me to take some free space from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda4 to create volume group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/sda3` is your root file system and you can't just convert it into an LVM volume with a simple command. The messages even tells you exactly this.

Comment: is it possible for me to take some free space from /dev/sda3 to /dev/sda4 to create volume group?

Comment: In theory, yes. It's quite involved though (resizing FS and partition, creating a new partition etc.) and I wouldn't even bother and just start over or backup/restore into a LVM.